# How to resize Popover window?

Tags: sapui5

I have created a [Popover](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Popover) that looks as follows:

[image]

How to set the `Popover` window smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you  just wanna show an information to the user use an **sap.m.MessageBox**.

```
    sap.m.MessageBox.information(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat"
        );
```

[image]

If you need **sap.m.Popover** go for sth. like this:

**contentWidth="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? '100%' : '20%'}"**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Popover title="Popover" placement="Bottom" contentWidth="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? '100%' : '20%'}" class="sapUiContentPadding">
    <Text
        text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."/>
</Popover>
```

</core:FragmentDefinition>

[image]